# Laravel request validation message formatting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation),

How to customize the **response format**?

For example, it shows error messages as:

```json
{
   "password":[
      "The password field is required."
   ],
   "password_confirmation":[
      "The password confirmation field is required."
   ]
}
```

I want to put all error messages into the description property, something like.

```json
{
   "status":false,
   "description":[
      "The password field is required.",
      "The password confirmation field is required."
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To pull out all the error messages into an array you would need to do something like this...

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'password' => 'required',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
]);

$messages = $validator->errors()->toArray();
/* ** This will give you something like this **
*
*       'password' => 'The password field is required.',
*       'password_confirmation' => 'The password confirmation field is required.'
*
* **/

// If you want only array values - as your example of description, then use php's array_values() method like this...

$description_arr = array_values($messages);
```

Thanks hope this will help you..!!
For better understanding of Laravel Validations go through its docs - [Laravel Validation Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

Answer (score 1):

It's right below in the doc link that you provided:

> You may customize the error messages used by the form request by
>   overriding the messages method. This method should return an array of
>   attribute / rule pairs and their corresponding error messages.

So, put this in your Request:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'password.required' => 'The password field is required.',
        'password_confirmation.required'  => 'The password confirmation field is required.',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       'password' => [ 'required' , 'min:4','confirmed' ] ,
       'password_confirmation' => [ 'required' , 'min:4' ]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method for creating custom validation messages would be to pass your own messages array to the `validate` function in your controller action. The `validate` function takes an array with custom messages as third parameter.

```php
public function listing(Request $request)
{
    $messages = [
        'search_input.alpha_dash' => 'Please enter a valid search term. Only use letters, dashes and underscores.',
    ];

    $this->validate($request, [
        'search_input' => 'alpha_dash',
    ], $messages);


    return view('videos.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is from 2016,

I answer this on 2021, because today I found the same problem.

if you are using Laravel 8 (as per today), this is what I did.

create your own formrequest, using `php artisan make:request IndonesiaInsertRequest` it will build a new class Custom

Inside the new class overwrite the `failedValidation` function like follow.

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator){
   $responseformat = ["myerror"=>$validator->errors()];
   new HttpResponseException(response()->json($responseformat, 200));
}
```

change `$responseformat` with any formar you want.